# How is it possible to call a method backwards like this?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have some isolated code that is seriously bending my brain:

```
Person caster = new Person(name: "Caster", age: 24);
Console.WriteLine(caster.ToString());
object o = caster;
Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
```

The output:

```
Caster is 24
Caster is 24
```

The implementation of `Person` is as you would expect. The only thing to remark is that I override `ToString` as depicted above.

How is this output possible? It makes sense that if you call `ToString` on a type that *derives* from `object` that either `Object.ToString` of a more specific implementation will be invoked.

But when we assign to `object` how can the runtime know to call `Person.ToString` instead of `Object.ToString`? Does this have something to do with Polymorphism? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, at runtime you have assigned a Person to object and since object has a ToString() method the super is ToString()'s method is invoked.

Comment: `caster.ToString()` should give string description of the object. You need to use public properties of `Person` class. for example: `caster.Name` or `caster.Age.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

That is known as Runtime Polymorphism by means of method overriding. since `tostring()` is overriden in your `caster` class when you do like below, method invocation gets resolved at runtime by the `actual type` and not by the `declared type`.

```
object o = caster;
Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
```

Here declared type is `Object` but the actual type is `Person` and so `tostring()` of `Person` gets invoked.

Comment: @Downvoter: Mind leaving a comment as well?

Comment: This is a good question, but it is obvious, that it has many answers on the internet. OP did not put enough effort to find the information and answering this question inspires low quality questions. It should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly, agreed and that should have been commented (likewise you did) but mustn't be down voted on a correct answer.

Comment: @Rahul I believe the idea is to penalize people who answer low-effort questions in order to discourage behavior that perpetuates the problem. If you can post a low-effort, no-research question and still get an answer, it encourages further low-effort, no-research questions.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly, there is absolutely no reason to punish an answer that is valid.  Rate each answer on its technical merit.

Comment: @DanielMann and Others, It's really shocking to see so many down votes on a valid and correct answer. If you think so then Be professional and flag it as low quality answer instead of down vote. Let Moderators/other decide if it's indeed low quality. I will accept the deletion of the answer.

Comment: @Rahul I didn't downvote your answer. I was just providing an explanation of the rationale that the downvoters were using.

Answer (score -1):

Its Runtime polymorphism , ToString method to return a string that represents the object instance. The runtime always traverse from most child to base class.

```
 Person caster = new Person(name: "Caster", age: 24);       
        object o = caster;
        Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());           
        Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
```

Here the real instance is caster ,as an evidence in above code o.GetType() shows Person as its type.